# draw multiple encoded polylines using api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a set of encoded polylines, retrieved from the result of direction service, and I have  stored them in a php array.

With the code below, I can add a single polyline. How do I modify it to add multiple polylines at the same time?

```
var code = '_mjsB{qp{LvAe@xImCjGgBf@St@Qf@Un@e@Hm@Pc@VW^MhAc@`B{@lAw@zCyA`@KvEyB`Ao@PQNK';

var paths = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(code);

var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path:pathss,
  strokeColor: "#0000FF",
  strokeOpacity: 1.0,
  strokeWeight: 2
}); flightPath.setMap(map);
```

Comment: This [POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379586/drawing-multiple-polyline-with-different-color-using-google-map-api-v3-asp-net) may help you

Answer (score 1):

Do you want all of your polylines to have the same styling, or do they need different styles for the different polylines? Let's assume they are the same for now; let me know if they need to be different and we can adjust the code.

So first, write the PHP code to generate a JavaScript array of your encoded paths. I'll let you sort out this part.

Then, write a simple loop in JavaScript to decode each path and add it to the map:

```
// These are the encoded paths generated from PHP
var encodedFlightPaths = [
    '...first-path...',
    '...second-path...',
    '...third-path...'
];

addEncodedPaths( encodedFlightPaths );

function addEncodedPaths( encodedPaths ) {
    for( var i = 0, n = encodedPaths.length;  i < n;  i++ ) {
        addEncodedPath( encodedPaths[i] );
    }
}

function addEncodedPath( encodedPath ) {
    var path = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath( encodedPath );

    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: path,
        strokeColor: "#0000FF",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });
    polyline.setMap( map );
}
```