# How do I display an array of encoded polylines?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps-api-3

I want to loop through an array of encoded polylines, displaying each individual polyline on the map.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601524/draw-multiple-encoded-polylines-using-api-v3) seems to have a good answer, but it's not working properly for me. The polylines are all a little off when I have more than one encoded polyline in the array.

This code works properly, but uses Rails to do the looping instead of JavaScript:

```
<script>
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 13,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(<%= @city.latitude.to_f %>,<%= @city.longitude.to_f %>),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

    <% @encoded_polylines.each_with_index do |encoded_polyline, index| %>
      var decodedPath<%= index %> = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath('<%= encoded_polyline %>');
      var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: decodedPath<%= index %>,
        strokeColor: "#663399",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
      });
      poly.setMap(map);
    <% end %>
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

The resulting map is correct:

[image: correctly displayed encoded polylines]

When I try to do the looping in JavaScript, all of the encoded polylines are displayed incorrectly:

```
<script>
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 13,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(<%= @city.latitude.to_f %>,<%= @city.longitude.to_f %>),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    };
    var map              = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    var encodedPolylines = <%= raw @encoded_polylines %>;
    var arrayLength      = encodedPolylines.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
      var decodedPath = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encodedPolylines[i])
      var poly        = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: decodedPath,
        strokeColor: "#663399",
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
      });
      poly.setMap(map);
    }
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

The resulting map is incorrect:

[image: correctly displayed encoded polylines]

If I send only one `encodedPolyline` item through the JavaScript code by using `var encodedPolylines = ['<%= raw @encoded_polylines.first %>'];` instead, then it displays that polyline correctly. If I send two `encodedPolyline` items through the JavaScript code by using `var encodedPolylines = <%= raw @encoded_polylines.first(2) %>;`, then it displays the polylines incorrectly.

I don't see any difference in the `encodedPolyline` data when looking at a value on its own (with the use of `.first`) or when looking at its value as it exists within the array.

The result of `var encodedPolylines = <%= raw @encoded_polylines.first(2) %>;` is:

```
var encodedPolylines = ["mjr`GlaizLBnDRHe@U@YAa@HWDYBWBYD]DYBYBYBWB]D_@@Y@YD_@H]FYHYTGRAF[?]AYB]C_@?_@Ca@E]EYC_@C]A_@A]E]A]Aa@C]E]AWC[AW@]E_@GY?W?_@CW?_@?WC[Ca@CY?WA_@?]AYC[G]?Y?]C]IU@_@A_@AY@[D[Dc@BYHYFYJUFULSLQLQJUHYHSJQJSLUJUJWHSJYNSHUDYJWNULUFWJUNYHSLYPUHSJ[LWPILSRQJSHWJUFWISMQOQQIOMSKOOSOQMKUOUOMOQOOSQSMMMOKOOSMOMOQOQKQMQQQQOSQOOQQMOQOOMOOOOQOSOOKSQOQOQQOMSSOOOOSSOMOOSOMOMOMMSE]KWQQQOSOSOQOQMQQQOQQ?a@D[F[FYHWHWJ[HWJUJULSNOPIDC", "{jr`Gbiiz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
```

The result of `var encodedPolylines = ['<%= raw @encoded_polylines.first %>'];` is:

```
var encodedPolylines = ['mjr`GlaizLBnDRHe@U@YAa@HWDYBWBYD]DYBYBYBWB]D_@@Y@YD_@H]FYHYTGRAF[?]AYB]C_@?_@Ca@E]EYC_@C]A_@A]E]A]Aa@C]E]AWC[AW@]E_@GY?W?_@CW?_@?WC[Ca@CY?WA_@?]AYC[G]?Y?]C]IU@_@A_@AY@[D[Dc@BYHYFYJUFULSLQLQJUHYHSJQJSLUJUJWHSJYNSHUDYJWNULUFWJUNYHSLYPUHSJ[LWPILSRQJSHWJUFWISMQOQQIOMSKOOSOQMKUOUOMOQOOSQSMMMOKOOSMOMOQOQKQMQQQQOSQOOQQMOQOOMOOOOQOSOOKSQOQOQQOMSSOOOOSSOMOOSOMOMOMMSE]KWQQQOSOSOQOQMQQQOQQ?a@D[F[FYHWHWJ[HWJUJULSNOPIDC'];
```

Comment: can you post an example-output for `<%= raw @encoded_polylines.first(2) %>` or give a link to a page that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: ok - I added both examples, just in case.

Comment: at least for me the result seems to be correct: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/L4uVa/

Comment: Except, with just the second encoded polyline, it's quite different. The polyline is actually supposed to look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nGSNA/

Comment: the  strings are different. Take a look at the backslashes, where your fiddle has 2 consecutive backslashes in the encoded line that you've posted are 4 consecutive backslashes

Comment: This is so interesting! If I display one encoded polyline on a map, then I need to escape the backslashes (which I do with `.gsub(/\\/,'\\\\\\')` on the polyline string). However, if I loop through an array of polylines (like I am above) I must not escape the backslashes. I didn't realize this, previously, and was encoding all generated polylines before they went into the database.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ruby but I guess there is some json-encoder running when you print the array with 2 items(notice that the encoded line in the array with 1 item is enclosed by single-quotes, while the array with 2 items uses double-quotes as it is required for JSON). A json-encoder usually will escape  the backslashes automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that if I display one encoded polyline on a map, then I need to escape the backslashes (which I do with `.gsub(/\\/,'\\\\\\')` on the polyline string).

However, if I loop through an array of polylines, I must **not** escape the backslashes.

I didn't realize this, and was applying the `gsub` while encoding all generated polylines as I was storing the `encoded_polyline` in the database.

I re-encoded all of the polylines without the `gsub`, and now the maps are displaying properly.