# Google Maps Multi color Multi Polyline strange behaviour

Tags: html, polyline

Please see the piece of code below :

[Sample Html](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1204823/GM_Multi_color_Multi_polyline.html)

There are two Polylines defined.
They are displayed OK, but both are displayed with Yellow color (even the first one is define with red color.

If I **switch** the definition order of the variables

var route**1** =

var route**2** =

to:

var route**2** =

var route**1** =

The routes will be displayed fine (yellow and red)

Can someone expalin to me what makes the difference here ?
Why is the order important ?

I have an automated process which creates the html code, and need to understand the reason for this behaviour.

Many thanks !!!

Comment: I cannot open your link: InvalidKeyOrUnauthorizedURLMapError

Answer (score 0):

I cannot open your link but I think you can find your answer here: [Drawing multiple polyline with different color using Google map api V3 ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379586/drawing-multiple-polyline-with-different-color-using-google-map-api-v3-asp-net)

Quoted top answer:

Certainly.  For instance suppose you know what colours you want to go with each line, let's assume you therefore have an array of colours which has a length equal to DrivePath.length - 1.

```
var Colors = [
    "#FF0000", 
    "#00FF00", 
    "#0000FF", 
    "#FFFFFF", 
    "#000000", 
    "#FFFF00", 
    "#00FFFF", 
    "#FF00FF"
];
```

Now, instead of drawing one polyline, draw a separate polyline for each coordinate.

```
for (var i = 0; i < DrivePath.length-1; i++) {
  var PathStyle = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [DrivePath[i], DrivePath[i+1]],
    strokeColor: Colors[i],
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    map: map
  });
}
```