# Map pollution data as a HeatMap?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, heatmap

I have a route (or: a list of points) with an associated weighted pollution value between 0 and 10. I want to map these points with Google Maps.

The first thing which came to my head is to use the Google Maps HeatMapLayer and its [WeightedLocations](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/heatmaplayer). For the weights I would use my pollution values and Google Maps would do the rest for me.

However, this solution raises one issue: The displayed heat (green-to-red color) will also depend on the density of my points. So if two points are close together (and this can be the case with my data), the heat will also increase, irrespective of its weight.

Is there a better solution to create such a pollution map with Google Maps which does not take into account the density of points, but only takes into account the weight?

Comment: Before you give up on your approach (which I think might work well), have you considered the radius parameter (the radius of influence)?

Comment: thanks for your help. I guess I would need to play around with the `radius` parameter.. However, I now decided to use a polyline and color it accordingly (similar as to how google displays traffic congestion). see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379586/drawing-multiple-polyline-with-different-color-using-google-map-api-v3-asp-net

Comment: I am having the same issue with heatmaps. I can change the radius, but in the points are very close together, the values are added and I would like to make an average as the question suggests. I am using the Android Maps API.