# Why Google Maps Polyline strokeColor always black?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have already draw some trajectories in Google Maps Api. But I want to give a different color to each trajectory. The problem is that the color always is black even when strokeColor is not '#0000'. Any ideas about what is happening? Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Simple Polylines</title>
<style>
   html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>

function initMap() {

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: {lat: -12, lng: -77},
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    });


    var aristas = map.data.loadGeoJson('aristas.geojson');
    var aristasPath = new google.maps.Polyline({    
      path: aristas,
      geodesic: true,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2
    });


    aristasPath.setMap(map);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drawing multiple polyline with different color using Google map api V3 ASP.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379586/drawing-multiple-polyline-with-different-color-using-google-map-api-v3-asp-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are [adding your polyline to the data layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data) with `.loadGeoJson`, that needs to be styled using the [data layer styling methods](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#style_geojson_data), not as a normal [`google.maps.Polyline`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polyline)

```
// Set the stroke width, and fill color for each polyline/polygon
map.data.setStyle({
  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
  strokeOpacity: 1.0,
  strokeWeight: 2
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/473sb6y3/3/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: {
      lat: -12,
      lng: -77
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  });


  var aristas = map.data.addGeoJson(platesJson);
  // Set the stroke width, and fill color for each polyline/polygon
  map.data.setStyle({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
var platesJson = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
    }
  },

  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "strnum": 420,
      "platecode": 201,
      "datatype": "TR",
      "dtnum": 1,
      "refnum": 9921,
      "appearance": 245.000000,
      "disappeara": -999.000000,
      "color": 7,
      "geogdesc": "PERU-CHILE TRENCH"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [-81.8796, -5.0707],
        [-81.876, -5.1257],
        [-81.8735, -5.2358],
        [-81.8737, -5.2473],
        [-81.8806, -5.3778],
        [-81.871, -5.4765],
        [-81.8638, -5.5843],
        [-81.8346, -5.736],
        [-81.8182, -5.8416],
        [-81.7953, -5.9634],
        [-81.7765, -6.0598],
        [-81.7624, -6.1654],
        [-81.7437, -6.2687],
        [-81.7293, -6.3536],
        [-81.7064, -6.4775],
        [-81.6682, -6.6405],
        [-81.6263, -6.7213],
        [-81.5982, -6.8087],
        [-81.5294, -6.9219],
        [-81.4834, -7.0347],
        [-81.4483, -7.1152],
        [-81.3914, -7.2533],
        [-81.3679, -7.3427],
        [-81.3469, -7.4436],
        [-81.3323, -7.5191],
        [-81.2998, -7.6201],
        [-81.2756, -7.673],
        [-81.2494, -7.7373],
        [-81.2318, -7.7764],
        [-81.2255, -7.8039],
        [-81.1969, -7.866],
        [-81.1661, -7.9327],
        [-81.1379, -8.0129],
        [-81.1037, -8.1434],
        [-81.0577, -8.2559],
        [-81.0115, -8.3547],
        [-80.9587, -8.4649],
        [-80.9126, -8.5682],
        [-80.8997, -8.6139],
        [-80.8439, -8.6855],
        [-80.8132, -8.7611],
        [-80.7695, -8.8688],
        [-80.7301, -8.965],
        [-80.6681, -9.0752],
        [-80.6064, -9.1967],
        [-80.5598, -9.2748],
        [-80.5088, -9.3598],
        [-80.4557, -9.4584],
        [-80.4184, -9.5408],
        [-80.3541, -9.6486],
        [-80.2921, -9.7608],
        [-80.2479, -9.8433],
        [-80.201, -9.9053],
        [-80.126, -10.0518],
        [-80.0703, -10.1298],
        [-80.0196, -10.2304],
        [-79.9303, -10.3452],
        [-79.8612, -10.4438],
        [-79.817, -10.5261],
        [-79.7463, -10.6608],
        [-79.6729, -10.7684],
        [-79.6218, -10.8507],
        [-79.5865, -10.9169],
        [-79.551, -10.9785],
        [-79.5266, -11.0151],
        [-79.4953, -11.0541],
        [-79.4757, -11.1086],
        [-79.4607, -11.1608],
        [-79.4388, -11.2131],
        [-79.3921, -11.2839],
        [-79.3566, -11.341],
        [-79.2965, -11.4323],
        [-79.2206, -11.5306],
        [-79.1829, -11.5899],
        [-79.1426, -11.6403],
        [-79.1004, -11.7064],
        [-79.0628, -11.7724],
        [-79.0273, -11.8293],
        [-78.9893, -11.8773],
        [-78.9271, -11.9752],
        [-78.8806, -12.0594],
        [-78.7889, -12.169],
        [-78.7083, -12.2582],
        [-78.6413, -12.3425],
        [-78.5833, -12.42],
        [-78.5209, -12.5088],
        [-78.4454, -12.6269],
        [-78.4124, -12.6948],
        [-78.377, -12.7606],
        [-78.3217, -12.858],
        [-78.2665, -12.9622],
        [-78.2089, -13.0619],
        [-78.1528, -13.1189],
        [-78.1058, -13.1713],
        [-78.0453, -13.2373],
        [-77.983, -13.3325],
        [-77.952, -13.3868],
        [-77.89, -13.4908],
        [-77.7986, -13.62],
        [-77.738, -13.677],
        [-77.6595, -13.7566],
        [-77.5585, -13.8589],
        [-77.5113, -13.9045],
        [-77.4488, -13.9837],
        [-77.3997, -14.0471],
        [-77.2988, -14.1516],
        [-77.2249, -14.2354],
        [-77.1801, -14.2831],
        [-77.0858, -14.3761],
        [-76.9742, -14.5207],
        [-76.9026, -14.6066],
        [-76.8151, -14.695],
        [-76.7568, -14.7539],
        [-76.6966, -14.8328],
        [-76.6426, -14.8805],
        [-76.6043, -14.9123],
        [-76.5272, -14.9426],
        [-76.5002, -14.9697],
        [-76.4512, -15.0372],
        [-76.3958, -15.1271],
        [-76.3718, -15.1919],
        [-76.2867, -15.2844],
        [-76.1922, -15.366],
        [-76.0885, -15.4455],
        [-75.9892, -15.5137],
        [-75.8835, -15.6065],
        [-75.8343, -15.6605],
        [-75.7868, -15.688],
        [-75.7211, -15.7223],
        [-75.6718, -15.7764],
        [-75.6115, -15.8527],
        [-75.5537, -15.9378],
        [-75.4955, -16.003],
        [-75.4324, -16.0527],
        [-75.3538, -16.1271],
        [-75.2975, -16.1723],
        [-75.2206, -16.2134],
        [-75.173, -16.2363],
        [-75.0938, -16.2819],
        [-75.0286, -16.3404],
        [-74.959, -16.4035],
        [-74.8848, -16.471],
        [-74.8082, -16.5297],
        [-74.788, -16.5499],
        [-74.6751, -16.6268],
        [-74.6052, -16.6766],
        [-74.4517, -16.7784],
        [-74.3209, -16.8732],
        [-74.1941, -16.9415],
        [-74.0948, -17.0092],
        [-74.0022, -17.0658],
        [-73.8987, -17.1534],
        [-73.7904, -17.23],
        [-73.6974, -17.2712],
        [-73.5977, -17.3169],
        [-73.4981, -17.3713],
        [-73.4422, -17.436],
        [-73.3863, -17.5006],
        [-73.3189, -17.5654],
        [-73.2204, -17.6746],
        [-73.1355, -17.7746],
        [-72.9596, -17.9025],
        [-72.8495, -18.0051],
        [-72.7776, -18.072],
        [-72.6854, -18.1523],
        [-72.6089, -18.2127],
        [-72.5661, -18.2484],
        [-72.4901, -18.3392],
        [-72.4277, -18.4211],
        [-72.352, -18.5271],
        [-72.2618, -18.5963],
        [-72.1823, -18.6217],
        [-72.1168, -18.6642],
        [-72.0611, -18.7371],
        [-72.0148, -18.825],
        [-71.8849, -18.9687],
        [-71.8676, -19.0169],
        [-71.8187, -19.0895],
        [-71.7944, -19.1355],
        [-71.7453, -19.1972],
        [-71.687, -19.259],
        [-71.6264, -19.3144],
        [-71.5974, -19.3539],
        [-71.5595, -19.4023],
        [-71.5149, -19.4595],
        [-71.4862, -19.512],
        [-71.4531, -19.5755],
        [-71.4317, -19.6538],
        [-71.3991, -19.741],
        [-71.3665, -19.826],
        [-71.3143, -19.9653],
        [-71.2905, -20.0327],
        [-71.2605, -20.1369],
        [-71.2512, -20.2472],
        [-71.2303, -20.3489],
        [-71.2043, -20.4226],
        [-71.1895, -20.4854],
        [-71.1863, -20.5565],
        [-71.186, -20.7739],
        [-71.1786, -20.8643],
        [-71.1853, -20.9737],
        [-71.1805, -21.079],
        [-71.1729, -21.1563],
        [-71.1613, -21.268],
        [-71.1497, -21.3753],
        [-71.1377, -21.4612],
        [-71.1416, -21.5445],
        [-71.1457, -21.6364],
        [-71.1538, -21.7004],
        [-71.1544, -21.7303],
        [-71.1794, -21.843],
        [-71.1858, -21.9326],
        [-71.1875, -22.02],
        [-71.1892, -22.1094],
        [-71.1845, -22.216],
        [-71.1851, -22.3607],
        [-71.181, -22.5031],
        [-71.1939, -22.5794],
        [-71.2321, -22.7739],
        [-71.2546, -22.871],
        [-71.2778, -23.004],
        [-71.2961, -23.1222],
        [-71.2834, -23.2873],
        [-71.2969, -23.3926],
        [-71.2989, -23.4917],
        [-71.2851, -23.6057],
        [-71.3027, -23.6855],
        [-71.3118, -23.7969],
        [-71.3184, -23.8977],
        [-71.328, -24.0383],
        [-71.3413, -24.1304],
        [-71.3664, -24.2412],
        [-71.3866, -24.3372],
        [-71.3787, -24.5132],
        [-71.3796, -24.6721],
        [-71.379, -24.7577],
        [-71.3746, -24.8809],
        [-71.3893, -25.0432],
        [-71.4122, -25.1552],
        [-71.4473, -25.3085],
        [-71.4826, -25.4741],
        [-71.4918, -25.588],
        [-71.4655, -25.6465],
        [-71.4655, -25.6465],
        [-71.4651, -25.7397],
        [-71.4719, -25.8493],
        [-71.4735, -25.9279],
        [-71.4806, -26.0538],
        [-71.4965, -26.1609],
        [-71.5245, -26.3006],
        [-71.5664, -26.4482],
        [-71.5889, -26.5445],
        [-71.6372, -26.6732],
        [-71.6522, -26.8474],
        [-71.6607, -26.9272],
        [-71.6882, -27.0415],
        [-71.7346, -27.188],
        [-71.7597, -27.2939],
        [-71.7892, -27.3955],
        [-71.8165, -27.5011],
        [-71.8336, -27.5559],
        [-71.8689, -27.6001],
        [-71.8882, -27.6527],
        [-71.9121, -27.7012],
        [-71.9463, -27.8064],
        [-71.9406, -27.8654],
        [-71.9393, -27.9142],
        [-71.9527, -28.0053]
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "strnum": 444,
      "platecode": 291,
      "datatype": "TR",
      "dtnum": 1,
      "refnum": 9921,
      "appearance": 245.000000,
      "disappeara": -999.000000,
      "color": 1,
      "geogdesc": "CHILE TRENCH"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [-71.9527, -28.0053],
        [-71.9851, -28.1366],
        [-72.0072, -28.2112],
        [-72.049, -28.3522],
        [-72.1035, -28.5534],
        [-72.1591, -28.7018],
        [-72.1887, -28.8041],
        [-72.2016, -28.8763],
        [-72.2217, -28.9645],
        [-72.2224, -28.9966],
        [-72.2242, -29.083],
        [-72.2368, -29.139],
        [-72.2514, -29.1829],
        [-72.2853, -29.2726],
        [-72.3071, -29.3284],
        [-72.305, -29.4486],
        [-72.3238, -29.5823],
        [-72.3395, -29.6779],
        [-72.3671, -29.7932],
        [-72.4251, -29.9397],
        [-72.4341, -30.0431],
        [-72.4545, -30.1441],
        [-72.4674, -30.2134],
        [-72.4695, -30.3126],
        [-72.4508, -30.4002],
        [-72.446, -30.4973],
        [-72.4499, -30.5725],
        [-72.4656, -30.6671],
        [-72.4835, -30.7597],
        [-72.4951, -30.872],
        [-72.4934, -31.1143],
        [-72.5261, -31.2572],
        [-72.5313, -31.3926],
        [-72.5351, -31.465],
        [-72.5439, -31.555],
        [-72.55, -31.6234],
        [-72.5487, -31.6723],
        [-72.5293, -31.7254],
        [-72.5256, -31.7684],
        [-72.5245, -31.8231],
        [-72.5325, -31.8738],
        [-72.5518, -31.9242],
        [-72.5717, -31.9979],
        [-72.5779, -32.0738],
        [-72.5789, -32.1205],
        [-72.5824, -32.1749],
        [-72.5832, -32.2118],
        [-72.5811, -32.2196],
        [-72.5679, -32.247],
        [-72.539, -32.2824],
        [-72.5237, -32.3157],
        [-72.5313, -32.3486],
        [-72.5503, -32.3851],
        [-72.5814, -32.4467],
        [-72.6154, -32.5373],
        [-72.6348, -32.5892],
        [-72.6401, -32.6259],
        [-72.6602, -32.7068],
        [-72.6663, -32.7782],
        [-72.6677, -32.8419],
        [-72.6664, -32.8882],
        [-72.6607, -32.9423],
        [-72.6531, -33.0118],
        [-72.6538, -33.0426],
        [-72.6551, -33.1023],
        [-72.6627, -33.1387],
        [-72.6772, -33.175],
        [-72.6909, -33.2767],
        [-72.741, -33.3757],
        [-72.7447, -33.4389],
        [-72.7695, -33.5267],
        [-72.7801, -33.5954],
        [-72.7779, -33.5974],
        [-72.7787, -33.6337],
        [-72.8056, -33.7136],
        [-72.844, -33.797],
        [-72.8591, -33.8597],
        [-72.8884, -33.9432],
        [-72.9127, -34.0114],
        [-72.953, -34.0774],
        [-73.0047, -34.1393],
        [-73.0723, -34.1991],
        [-73.1331, -34.2609],
        [-73.1892, -34.315],
        [-73.2542, -34.3615],
        [-73.2915, -34.3912],
        [-73.3522, -34.449],
        [-73.3993, -34.5127],
        [-73.4605, -34.5912],
        [-73.5054, -34.6567],
        [-73.5739, -34.7557],
        [-73.6333, -34.8585],
        [-73.6578, -34.9297],
        [-73.6772, -34.9803],
        [-73.704, -35.0532],
        [-73.7327, -35.1129],
        [-73.7596, -35.1895],
        [-73.7817, -35.2586],
        [-73.7949, -35.3353],
        [-73.7988, -35.4082],
        [-73.7928, -35.4476],
        [-73.7942, -35.5074],
        [-73.8133, -35.5445],
        [-73.8284, -35.6078],
        [-73.9549, -35.8464],
        [-74.0473, -35.9901],
        [-74.0809, -36.0583],
        [-74.1119, -36.1154],
        [-74.1667, -36.2147],
        [-74.2074, -36.2937],
        [-74.2436, -36.3764],
        [-74.2817, -36.4442],
        [-74.3294, -36.534],
        [-74.3493, -36.6019],
        [-74.4045, -36.719],
        [-74.4342, -36.816],
        [-74.4744, -36.977],
        [-74.5134, -37.081],
        [-74.5509, -37.2213],
        [-74.5626, -37.3344],
        [-74.5716, -37.4273],
        [-74.5808, -37.5274],
        [-74.5841, -37.5711],
        [-74.5954, -37.6673],
        [-74.6012, -37.7199],
        [-74.6033, -37.8106],
        [-74.6044, -37.8577],
        [-74.6129, -37.9301],
        [-74.6214, -38.0023],
        [-74.6304, -38.0926],
        [-74.6311, -38.1215],
        [-74.6372, -38.19],
        [-74.6335, -38.228],
        [-74.6413, -38.2657],
        [-74.6769, -38.3247],
        [-74.7377, -38.3796],
        [-74.7829, -38.4581],
        [-74.8232, -38.5204],
        [-74.8643, -38.6149],
        [-74.8795, -38.6775],
        [-74.8896, -38.7167],
        [-74.8837, -38.758],
        [-74.878, -38.8082],
        [-74.8814, -38.8564]
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "strnum": 445,
      "platecode": 292,
      "datatype": "TR",
      "dtnum": 1,
      "refnum": 9921,
      "appearance": 245.000000,
      "disappeara": -999.000000,
      "color": 7,
      "geogdesc": "CHILE TRENCH"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [-74.8814, -38.8564],
        [-74.9212, -38.897],
        [-74.9545, -38.9501],
        [-74.9628, -39.0142],
        [-74.9619, -39.073],
        [-74.9672, -39.1033],
        [-74.9822, -39.1582],
        [-75.0043, -39.222],
        [-75.0197, -39.2911],
        [-75.0335, -39.3956],
        [-75.0417, -39.4523],
        [-75.0439, -39.5443],
        [-75.0456, -39.6168],
        [-75.0474, -39.6893],
        [-75.0467, -39.7599],
        [-75.0489, -39.8516],
        [-75.0503, -39.9114],
        [-75.0486, -39.9343],
        [-75.0458, -40.0065],
        [-75.0037, -40.0086],
        [-74.9999, -40.0368],
        [-75.003, -40.0614],
        [-75.0127, -40.0806],
        [-75.0175, -40.0893],
        [-75.034, -40.1048],
        [-75.0692, -40.1323],
        [-75.093, -40.1635],
        [-75.1242, -40.2122],
        [-75.1412, -40.2435],
        [-75.1542, -40.2959],
        [-75.165, -40.35],
        [-75.1709, -40.3954],
        [-75.1819, -40.4565],
        [-75.1901, -40.5001],
        [-75.1987, -40.5576],
        [-75.2067, -40.5958],
        [-75.2124, -40.6324],
        [-75.2182, -40.6759],
        [-75.2195, -40.7177],
        [-75.2137, -40.7544],
        [-75.2101, -40.7858],
        [-75.2017, -40.8103],
        [-75.1936, -40.847],
        [-75.1924, -40.8835],
        [-75.2003, -40.9181],
        [-75.2151, -40.9508],
        [-75.2485, -40.9954],
        [-75.2723, -41.0262],
        [-75.2919, -41.0675],
        [-75.3087, -41.0949],
        [-75.3331, -41.143],
        [-75.356, -41.2187]
      ]
    }
  }]
};
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks that works for the case when I have just one variable loaded with .loadGeojson. But what if I have loaded more variables with .loadGeojson?

Comment: Then you need to write more complicated code.  See the documentation I pointed to.